# git clone results in: "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, ssh

I want to clone a new project with a command like

`git clone git@some_link.com:some_word/project_name.git`

But it keeps giving me the error

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname some_link.com:some_word: Name or service not known`

when I got this error trying to clone from github, I added my ssh key to github.com. How would I do that here?

Comment: `Could not resolve hostname` suggests that your network connection is flaky (or your DNS). Beside, it's a little hard to understand some parts of your question, e.g: *But here where i want to add my key?*

Comment: Sorry for my bad english."But here where i want to" means,,In this case, where i want to add my ssh-key to the remote system..As I did in github.

Comment: And I don't know why u people giving me down vote for my bad english?? I don't think that is a great mistake of mine.

Comment: I think the downvote(s) are because the question is really vague.

Comment: Change the title of this question if it no longer concerns the "fatal: remote end hung up unexpectedly" error, because it keeps showing up in Google results for that issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these:

```
git clone user@host:/path/to/repository/project_name.git
git clone ssh://user@host/path/to/repository/project_name.git
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a repo you have write access to, use `ssh-copy-id` to copy your identity. Google can provide a simple script that does the same thing for OSX (`ssh-copy-id` is just a simple script afaik). On windows, I have no clue, unless you're using Cygwin, in which case it should just be `ssh-copy-id`.

If it's not a repo you have write access to, make the url `http://somewhere.tld/path/to/repo.git` or `https://somewhere.tld/path/to/repo.git`

If it's a repo you *should* have access to, but don't (like say on a shared host or something), you might just need to add it in a control panel or contact support.

From the error, it may be misspelled. If the above doesn't fix your issue, could you post the exact command and output you're using and seeing?